# Windows 10 WiFi stops when downloading large files

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, network-adapter

My new desktop has been having this issue where when I start to download a large file. It’ll automatically cut out after a few. It doesn’t cut out when I’m watching a video or something small. The WiFi in my house is fine, and when the pc WiFi cuts out, the WiFi still works on other devices. I’ve tried a lot of things, and it doesn’t seem to work. I’m running Windows 10 pro currently. The computer itself doesn’t have a WiFi adapter built-in, so I have an 802.11 dongle.

Here what I’ve tried:

- Updating WiFi driver
- Disallow power management to shut down adaptor
- Checked the bandwidth connection from the internet. (580 down, 340 up)

Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried all of these items mentioned in this[link](https://windowsreport.com/wifi-connection-drops-when-downloading/)?

Comment: Link-only answers may provide an answer, but it's infinitely preferable to provide an explanation in text as well, just in case the link disappears. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer for detail